# New everyplay game Ads SDK (Unity ads) gives error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ads, everyplay

Well Yesterday (13,06,2014) Everyplay send a email and they said "new SDK published" but after establishing this SDK it gives this error and dont show any ads. in past it didnt give this error.

> 06-14 10:42:00.460: E/UnityAds(32338): com.unity3d.ads.android.d.a.a() (line:-1) :: Couldn't get isDestroyed -method
>   06-14 10:42:06.055: E/UnityAds(32338): com.unity3d.ads.android.campaign.UnityAdsCampaign.shouldCacheVideo() (line:-1) :: Key not found for campaign: 000000000000000000000001
>   06-14 10:42:06.055: E/UnityAds(32338): com.unity3d.ads.android.campaign.UnityAdsCampaign.shouldCacheVideo() (line:-1) :: Key not found for campaign: 000000000000000000000001
>   06-14 10:42:06.055: E/UnityAds(32338): com.unity3d.ads.android.campaign.UnityAdsCampaign.shouldCacheVideo() (line:-1) :: Key not found for campaign: 000000000000000000000002
>   06-14 10:42:06.055: E/UnityAds(32338): com.unity3d.ads.android.campaign.UnityAdsCampaign.shouldCacheVideo() (line:-1) :: Key not found for campaign: 000000000000000000000002
>   06-14 10:42:19.318: E/UnityAds(32338): com.unity3d.ads.android.UnityAds.show() (line:-1) :: Could not find activity: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@4230b028

Comment: Any solution working solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've double checked the migration guide, "Could not find activity:" sounds like you've upgraded the JAR used, but not the new AndroidManifest.xml contents.

SDK internals, build system and integration have been polished a bit when upgrading from Applifier Impact/Everyplay GameAds era to Unity Ads SDK.

With Android version, it means that there's a new Android project library that's preferred to be used instead of manually fiddling with JAR's and adding stuff to AndroidManifest.xml, with library projects it's handled automatically. The base class initialisation and singleton pattern has also been upgraded to be safer and easier to use

Importing new library project: https://github.com/Applifier/unity-ads/wiki/Integration-Guide-for-Android

Migration guide: https://github.com/Applifier/unity-ads/wiki/Transition-from-Applifier-Impact-and-Everyplay-GameAds